# Exportar resultado a un word

Tags: r

Parto de dos df:

```
d1 = data.frame(col1=c(11,3,3,4,11,6,7),
              col2=c("rojo","verde","amarillo","amarillo 23","pepe","marta","lento"),
              col3=c(150,250,50,100,300,125,200))

d2 = data.frame(col1=c(1,2,3,3),
              col2=c("morado","rojo","amarillo 23","marta"),
              col3=c(165,165,100,95))
```

La columna col1 es el ID. Quiero ver si hay algún ID repetido.

```
registros_d1 <- duplicated(d1$col1)
registros_d2 <- duplicated(d2$col1)
```

Los ordeno:

```
dupli1 <- sort(d1[registros_d1 ,]$col1 )
dupli2 <- sort(d2[registros_d2 ,]$col1)
```

Hago una función que me dice quién está repetido:

```
  duplicidad <- function() {
    
    if (length(dupli1)> 0 & length(dupli2)> 0 ) {
      x <-  paste ("ID REPETIDOS EN D1:", paste0(dupli1, collapse=", " ),"ID REPETIDOS EN D2:",paste0(dupli2, collapse=", " ))
      
    }
    
    else if (length(dupli1)> 0){
      x <- paste("ID REPETIDOS EN D1::", paste0(dupli1, collapse=", " ))
    }
    else if (length(dupli2)> 0){
      x <- paste("ID REPETIDOS EN D2:", paste0(dupli2, collapse=", " ))
      
      
    } else { 
      x <- paste("No hay duplicidades")
    }
    
    return(x)
  }
```

Quiero pasar el resultado a un documento de word. (No puedo usar rmarkdown)

Creo el documento:

```
library(officer)

doc <- read_docx()
```

Escribo en el documento:

```
doc <- doc  %>%
  body_add_par("PRUEBA") %>%
  body_add_par("") %>%
  body_add_par( duplicidad() )
```

Guardo el documento:

```
print(doc, target = "DOC.docx")
```

Si abro el documento me sale

> PRUEBA
>
> ID REPETIDOS EN D1: 3, 11 ID REPETIDOS EN D2: 2

Ahora quiero meter un salto de linea de forma que me escriba dos frases.

```
duplicidad <- function() {
  
  if ( length(dupli1)> 0 & length(dupli2)> 0 ) {
    x <-  paste ("ID REPETIDOS EN D1:", paste0(dupli1, collapse=", " ),"\n\nID REPETIDOS EN D2:",paste0(dupli2, collapse=", " ),sep="\n")
    
  }
  
  else if ( length(dupli1)> 0){
    x <- paste("ID REPETIDOS EN D1::", paste0(dupli1, collapse=", " ))
  }
  else if ( length(dupli2)> 0){
    x <- paste("ID REPETIDOS EN D2:", paste0(dupli2, collapse=", " ))
    
    
  } else { 
    x <- paste("No hay duplicidades")
  }
  
  return(cat(x))
}
```

Pero si vuelvo a crear el documento no me lo escribe. No pilla el salto de línea.

Answer (score 1):

Los párrafos justamente son una estructura que no contiene saltos de línea, si necesitas algo así, en realidad estás necesitando nuevos párrafos. Puedes partir de `duplicidad()` y dividir el resultado en un vector por cada salto y luego aplicar un nuevo párrafo, pero `duplicidad()` tiene que retornar el vector, ahora no esta retornando nada por que estás haciendo un `return(cat(x))` (`cat` no retorna nada), modifica el retorno por `return(x)`, luego simplemente puedes hacer algo así:

```
# Separamos cada línea por \n
duplicidad() %>% 
  strsplit("\n") %>%
  unlist() -> lineas

# Agregamos cada línea en un nuevo párrafo
for (linea in lineas) {
  body_add_par(doc, linea)
}
```

Comment: No sé el motivo pero el orden de las frases se escribe del revés en el word. Si imprimo "lineas" sale FRASE1, FRASE2. Cuando lo paso al word: FRASE2, FRASE1

Comment: hay alguna forma de hacer q el for (linea in lineas) vaya del revés? Empezando por la última?

Comment: No comprendo pq salen las frases del revés, pero haciendo un "reverso de lineas"   for (linea in rev(lineas))  sale bien.

Comment: Te puede servir invertir el orden de la lista con `rev()` por ejemplo: `for (linea in rev(lineas))`